# Getting lag while scrolling AQGridView items

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, aqgridview

i have AQGridView view with 45 items in GridView (12 rows), problem occurs when I scroll the view and grid gets laggy when new row is created. I am thinking about creating the whole rows once and using it from cache or something, without asking to create it every time when I scroll, because it's not usable and doesn't look fine when it lags. Thanks

```
- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) `enter code here`index
{
    NSString *fullThumbPath = [itemsList objectAtIndex:index];
    int startOfThumbWord = [fullThumbPath rangeOfString:@"bundle"].location;
    NSString *shortThumbPath = [fullThumbPath substringFromIndex:startOfThumbWord+7];
    if (
        ([vieta isEqualToString:@"cover"] || [vieta isEqualToString:@""]) && [labelis isEqualToString:@""]) {
        static NSString * PlainCellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
        AFInstallerImageCell2 * plainCell2 = (AFInstallerImageCell2 *)[aGridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
            plainCell2 = [[AFInstallerImageCell2 alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 150.0) // 330
                                                    reuseIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];

    plainCell2.selectionStyle = AQGridViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    plainCell2.path = [target stringByAppendingPathComponent:shortThumbPath];//[itemsList objectAtIndex:index];
    plainCell2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[itemsList objectAtIndex:index]];
    plainCell2.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    NSString *shortThumbPath = [fullThumbPath substringFromIndex:startOfThumbWord+30];

    shortThumbPath = [shortThumbPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/Thumb.png"
                                         withString:@""];

    NSString *title = [[shortThumbPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    plainCell2.title = [title stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
    return ( plainCell2 );
}
```

Comment: can you please share some code that you have implemented?

Comment: i would like to see your cell for index method

Comment: Okay, here is my [method](http://pastebin.com/3wKNM2JZ)

Comment: @IgnasS Please edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating plain **plainCell2** again and again

> Using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier for the tableView/gridview, you can
>   greatly speed things up. Instead of instantiating a lot of cells, you
>   just instantiate as many as needed, i.e. as many that are visible
>   (this is handled automatically).But you are creating a new one each
>   time

**Replace this**

```
 AFInstallerImageCell2 * plainCell2 = (AFInstallerImageCell2 *)[aGridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
            plainCell2 = [[AFInstallerImageCell2 alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 150.0) // 330
                                                    reuseIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
```

**with this**

```
     AFInstallerImageCell2 * plainCell2 = (AFInstallerImageCell2 *)[aGridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
              if(plainCell2 ==nil) { 
plainCell2 = [[AFInstallerImageCell2 alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 150.0) // 330
                                                        reuseIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, it doesn't speed things up. Anyway, thank you for a help!

Comment: This is the only issue i can see in the above code. if there is something that you are doing other than that please add it too